# SQL: Replacing Multiple Nulls with unique values

Tags: sql, null, coalesce

For example, if column1 has a bunch of descriptions and multiple NULLs, and I want to replace each NULL with a unique description.

using a COALESCE function I can do

`COALESCE(Column1,'Description')`

and this will replace every NULL in the column with "description", how can I adress each NULL individually and not replace all of them with the same value?

Comment: Replace `NULL`s with what exactly? You should describe the logic that you want.

Comment: just unique string values

Comment: use a variable.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: you want to replace based on what criteria

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: The first part of your question is great, you describe a use case and include an example of replacing NULL with a static value. However, as others have suggested, the second part of your question should better-describe the logic you're trying to achieve. For example, are you looking to replace NULLs with: a random value (unique per row)? another column's value? a unique value based on some other column? or something else?

Comment: Ok for full clerification, I am using SSMS, and my assignment was to select ceartain columns, and "If the cell is NULL, provide a descriptive phrase instead of the word NULL." The column contains several rows of string values and several NULLs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide first you are replacing the nulls based on what criteria.Then you can use CASE to decide individual description for each criteria or condition.
Here below i have taken the criteria of Row number

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT NULL id
             FROM   dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT NULL
             FROM   dual),
         d1
         AS (SELECT ROWNUM rw,
                    d.*
             FROM   data d)
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN rw = 1 THEN COALESCE(id, 'star')
             ELSE COALESCE(id, 'moon')
           END AS id
    FROM   d1;
```